# How can I define HTML element classes with twig pattern fields?

Tags: theming

I want to use drupal fields to define class names in ui_patterns. i.e. define a field in a pattern twig.html file and use its {{ twig variable }} as a class name. The following doesn't work. Is there a correct way of doing this? is it even possible?

```
{%
set classes = [
'class_name_1',
'class_name_2',
{{ ui_yml_field_name }},
]
%}
<div{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
```

Comment: did you try with  `{%
set classes = [
'class_name_1',
'class_name_2',
ui_yml_field_name | clean_class,
]
%}`

Comment: thanks for reply i tried it and im getting:

Notice: Array to string conversion in Drupal\Component\Utility\Html::getClass() (line 72 of core/lib/Drupal/Component/Utility/Html.php).
Drupal\Component\Utility\Html::getClass(Array) (Line: 49)
__TwigTemplate_ddb65c76487dfa5f92a07810ee0bb1f930c92420b8295724a652ee64e58d84b6->doDisplay(Array, Array) (Line: 428)
Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array) (Line: 399)
Twig_Template->display(Array) (Line: 407)
Twig_Template->render(Array) (Line: 64)

Comment: the drupal field is a text list and the user selects a choice with a select box. the value prints fine as a {{ variable }} but is treated an array in your example.

Comment: ive tried outputting some different combinations:


variable=fade (correct user selection from a text list)

variable|render|clean_class=__----------div-classfield-field--name-field-entry-position-field--type-list-string-field--label-hidden-field--itemfade-div------

variable|clean_class=array

I want the the first one as a usable string to insert into the class array.

Comment: also tried replacing the entire format above with <div class={{"class #{ui_yml_field_name}"}}>. again, not working.

Comment: try `ui_yml_field_name['#items'][0].value`

Comment: thanks. step in the right direction but not the selected value. i cant see any useful variables in devel tabs.

Comment: putting a trace on it... ui_yml_field_name = array:1 [▼
  "field_entry_position" => array:17 [▶]
]

Comment: array:17 [▼
  "#theme" => "field"
  "#title" => "entry_position"
  "#label_display" => "hidden"
  "#view_mode" => "default"
  "#language" => "en"
  "#field_name" => "field_entry_position"
  "#field_type" => "list_string"
  "#field_translatable" => false
  "#entity_type" => "paragraph"
  "#bundle" => "slidecard"
  "#object" => Paragraph {#1134 ▶}
  "#items" => FieldItemList {#2141 ▶}
  "#formatter" => "list_key"
  "#is_multiple" => false
  0 => array:2 [▶]
  "#cache" => array:3 [▶]
  "#weight" => 2
]

Answer (score 1):

yaml_field_name.field_drupal_machine_name[0]['#markup'] gave me the selection. problem solved.